# How to adjust legend in standard R plot?

Tags: r

Is it possible to adjust legend with many names ?

I'm using this

```
legend("topleft", legend=c("mm8_12598_altPromoter","mm8_1457_starngeSplice",
"mm8_148_atac_Intron","mm8_1599_altFinish","mm8_2646_altThreePrime",
"mm8_2953_retainedIntron","mm8_8308_cassette_exon","mm8_8645_bleeding_exon",
"mm8_altFivePrime_1404"), col=linecols, pch=15, bty="o")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "adjust"?   What do you want to do?

Comment: I guess the only solutions would be to make the font smaller or to write the info in the figure legend, rather then on the figure itself.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I am assuming you want to adjust the position.

Try:

```
legend(x_position, y_position, legend=c("mm8_12598_altPromoter","mm8_1457_starngeSplice",
"mm8_148_atac_Intron","mm8_1599_altFinish","mm8_2646_altThreePrime",
"mm8_2953_retainedIntron","mm8_8308_cassette_exon","mm8_8645_bleeding_exon",
"mm8_altFivePrime_1404"), col=linecols, pch=15, bty="o")
```

And you can play around with the values, until you get it just right.